# Can't create SAP's user through JCo API drived by OIM

Tags: java, oracle, oim, sapjco3

I'm trying to create an SAP user from OIM using the sapjco3.jar library, but I'm getting an error in the create process:

On OIM side, below is the exception:

> ```
> ####<Oct 31, 2017 2:11:54 PM CST> <Notice> <Stdout> <rom-des-idm-03> 
> <WLS_OIM1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default 
> (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> 
> <d856d940a26e4902:19f8dd69:15ef3885641:-8000-00000000001fb6a1> 
> <1509480714560> 
> <BEA-000000> <<Oct 31, 2017 2:11:54 PM CST> <Error> 
> <ORACLE.IAM.CONNECTORS.ICFCOMMON.PROV.ICPROVISIONINGMANAGER> <BEA-000000> 
> <oracle.iam.connectors.icfcommon.prov.ICProvisioningManager : createObject : 
> Error while creating user
> org.identityconnectors.framework.common.exceptions.ConnectorException: Error 
> creating user 'AAA.AAA'.null
>     at org.identityconnectors.sap.Create.execute(Create.java:429)
>     at org.identityconnectors.sap.SAPConnector.create(SAPConnector.java:221)
>     at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.CreateImpl.create(CreateImpl.java:80)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16395.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ```

A NullPointerException, that's the only information I have from OIM logs.

And below is the exception from JCo log :

> ```
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-
>    tuning)' [14:11:54:380]: [JCoAPI] JCoClient.connect success with handle 
>    [1/84936186]
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-
>    tuning)' [14:11:54:380]: [JCoAPI] PoolingFactory.getClient() on pool SAP_SINERGIA|CONFIGURED_USER&100|OIMUSER|ES|2E545FD526DF90E53EA765E2FFDFAE37|CPIC0
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-
>    tuning)' [14:11:54:382]: [JCoAPI] PoolingFactory.getClient() returns handle [1/84936186]
>      invoked at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.PoolingFactory.getClient(PoolingFactory.java:604)
>      invoked at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.ConnectionManager.getClient(ConnectionManager.java:115)
>      invoked at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.Context.getConnection(Context.java:194)
>      invoked at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.RfcDestination.ping(RfcDestination.java:1418)
>      invoked at org.identityconnectors.sap.SAPConnector.checkAlive(SAPConnector.java:193)
>      invoked at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.ConnectorPoolManager$ConnectorPoolHandler.testObject(ConnectorPoolManager.java:105)
>      invoked at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.ConnectorPoolManager$ConnectorPoolHandler.testObject(ConnectorPoolManager.java:74)
>      invoked at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.ObjectPool.borrowObject(ObjectPool.java:229)
>      invoked at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.ConnectorAPIOperationRunnerProxy.invoke(ConnectorAPIOperationRunnerProxy.java:83)
>      invoked at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy575.schema(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16394.invoke(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>      invoked at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>      invoked at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.ThreadClassLoaderManagerProxy.invoke(ThreadClassLoaderManagerProxy.java:107)
>      invoked at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy575.schema(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16394.invoke(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>      invoked at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>      invoked at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.DelegatingTimeoutProxy.invoke(DelegatingTimeoutProxy.java:107)
>      invoked at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy575.schema(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16394.invoke(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>      invoked at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>      invoked at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.LoggingProxy.invoke(LoggingProxy.java:76)
>      invoked at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy575.schema(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.AbstractConnectorFacade.schema(AbstractConnectorFacade.java:112)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.connectors.icfcommon.prov.ICProvisioningManager.getConnectorSchema(ICProvisioningManager.java:979)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.connectors.icfcommon.prov.ICProvisioningManager.createObject(ICProvisioningManager.java:279)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>      invoked at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.adapterGlue.ScheduleItemEvents.adpSAPUMCREATE.SAPUMCREATE(adpSAPUMCREATE.java:109)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.adapterGlue.ScheduleItemEvents.adpSAPUMCREATE.implementation(adpSAPUMCREATE.java:54)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.client.events.tcBaseEvent.run(tcBaseEvent.java:210)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcDataObj.runEvent(tcDataObj.java:2496)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcScheduleItem.runMilestoneEvent(tcScheduleItem.java:3383)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcScheduleItem.eventPostInsert(tcScheduleItem.java:805)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcDataObj.insert(tcDataObj.java:606)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcDataObj.save(tcDataObj.java:478)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcORC.insertNonConditionalMilestones(tcORC.java:847)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcORC.completeSystemValidationMilestone(tcORC.java:1162)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcOrderItemInfo.completeCarrierBaseMilestone(tcOrderItemInfo.java:973)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcOrderItemInfo.eventPostInsert(tcOrderItemInfo.java:188)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcUDProcess.eventPostInsert(tcUDProcess.java:240)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcDataObj.insert(tcDataObj.java:606)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcDataObj.save(tcDataObj.java:478)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcTableDataObj.save(tcTableDataObj.java:2931)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcUDProcess.save(tcUDProcess.java:1130)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcORC.autoDOBSave(tcORC.java:3008)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.util.tcOrderPackages.createOrder(tcOrderPackages.java:474)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.util.tcOrderPackages.orderPackageForUser(tcOrderPackages.java:180)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcOIU.provision(tcOIU.java:869)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcOIU.eventPostInsert(tcOIU.java:364)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcDataObj.insert(tcDataObj.java:606)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcDataObj.save(tcDataObj.java:478)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcTableDataObj.save(tcTableDataObj.java:2931)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcUserProvisionObject.insertImplementation(tcUserProvisionObject.java:289)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcDataObj.insert(tcDataObj.java:595)
>      invoked at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcDataObj.save(tcDataObj.java:478)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.provisioning.spi.DOBProvisioningUtil.provisionObject(DOBProvisioningUtil.java:299)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.provisioning.spi.DOBProvisioningMechanism$1.process(DOBProvisioningMechanism.java:587)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.provisioning.spi.DOBProvisioningMechanism$1.process(DOBProvisioningMechanism.java:582)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.tx.OIMTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(OIMTransactionCallback.java:13)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.tx.OIMTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(OIMTransactionCallback.java:6)
>      invoked at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:128)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.tx.OIMTransactionManager.oimExecute(OIMTransactionManager.java:46)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.provisioning.spi.DOBProvisioningMechanism.provisionWithinTransaction(DOBProvisioningMechanism.java:581)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.provisioning.spi.DOBProvisioningMechanism.provision(DOBProvisioningMechanism.java:446)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.provisioning.impl.ProvisioningServiceImpl.provision(ProvisioningServiceImpl.java:547)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20577.invoke(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>      invoked at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>      invoked at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
>      invoked at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
>      invoked at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.utils.DMSMethodInterceptor.invoke(DMSMethodInterceptor.java:35)
>      invoked at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>      invoked at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>      invoked at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy483.provision(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.provisioning.handlers.ProvisionAppInstanceActionHandler.execute(ProvisionAppInstanceActionHandler.java:286)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.provisioning.handlers.ProvisionAppInstanceActionHandler.execute(ProvisionAppInstanceActionHandler.java:65)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.OIMEvent.executeHandlers(OIMEvent.java:214)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.MonitoredOIMEvent.invokeExecuteHandler(MonitoredOIMEvent.java:99)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.MonitoredOIMEvent.executeHandlers(MonitoredOIMEvent.java:69)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.OIMEvent.execute(OIMEvent.java:157)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.ProcessImpl.executeStage(ProcessImpl.java:223)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.OIMProcess.doStageExecution(OIMProcess.java:62)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.ProcessImpl.execute(ProcessImpl.java:182)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.MonitoredOIMProcess.execute(MonitoredOIMProcess.java:33)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.Utils.manageSyncProcessing(Utils.java:73)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.OrchestrationEngineImpl.doProcessing(OrchestrationEngineImpl.java:357)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.OrchestrationEngineImpl.orchestrate(OrchestrationEngineImpl.java:349)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.kernel.impl.OrchestrationEngineImpl.orchestrate(OrchestrationEngineImpl.java:393)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.request.impl.RequestEngine.startOrchestrationFromPreProcess(RequestEngine.java:5050)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.request.impl.RequestEngine.triggerOperation(RequestEngine.java:4976)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.request.impl.RequestEngine.doOperation(RequestEngine.java:4608)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.impl.OIMServiceImpl.doOperation(OIMServiceImpl.java:43)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20641.invoke(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>      invoked at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>      invoked at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
>      invoked at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
>      invoked at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.platform.utils.DMSMethodInterceptor.invoke(DMSMethodInterceptor.java:35)
>      invoked at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>      invoked at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>      invoked at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy354.doOperation(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.api.OIMServiceEJB.doOperationx(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20652.invoke(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>      invoked at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>      invoked at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
>      invoked at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
>      invoked at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
>      invoked at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
>      invoked at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
>      invoked at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>      invoked at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.visit(MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.java:34)
>      invoked at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.callback(EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.java:54)
>      invoked at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.EnvironmentInterceptor.invoke(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:42)
>      invoked at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>      invoked at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
>      invoked at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>      invoked at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
>      invoked at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
>      invoked at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>      invoked at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>      invoked at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy559.doOperationx(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.api.OIMService_1soh89_OIMServiceRemoteImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:40)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.api.OIMService_1soh89_OIMServiceRemoteImpl.doOperationx(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.api.OIMService_1soh89_OIMServiceRemoteImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at weblogic.rmi.internal.ServerRequest.sendReceive(ServerRequest.java:174)
>      invoked at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:347)
>      invoked at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:261)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.api.OIMService_1soh89_OIMServiceRemoteImpl_1036_WLStub.doOperationx(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>      invoked at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>      invoked at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:89)
>      invoked at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy558.doOperationx(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.api.OIMServiceDelegate.doOperation(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.ui.catalog.model.am.CatalogAMImpl.doOperation(CatalogAMImpl.java:2997)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.ui.catalog.model.am.CatalogAMImpl.submitCatalogWithScanID(CatalogAMImpl.java:2175)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.ui.catalog.model.am.CatalogAMImpl.submitCatalog(CatalogAMImpl.java:2155)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>      invoked at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCInvokeMethod.invokeMethod(DCInvokeMethod.java:690)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCDataControl.invokeMethod(DCDataControl.java:2181)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.model.bc4j.DCJboDataControl.invokeMethod(DCJboDataControl.java:3141)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCInvokeMethod.callMethod(DCInvokeMethod.java:262)
>      invoked at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlActionBinding.doIt(JUCtrlActionBinding.java:1708)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCDataControl.invokeOperation(DCDataControl.java:2188)
>      invoked at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlActionBinding.invoke(JUCtrlActionBinding.java:789)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PageLifecycleImpl.executeEvent(PageLifecycleImpl.java:410)
>      invoked at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlActionBinding._execute(FacesCtrlActionBinding.java:252)
>      invoked at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlActionBinding.execute(FacesCtrlActionBinding.java:210)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.ui.platform.utils.FacesUtils.executeOperationBinding(FacesUtils.java:182)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.ui.platform.utils.FacesUtils.executeOperationBindingFromActionListener(FacesUtils.java:124)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.ui.catalog.view.backing.CartReqBean.submit(CartReqBean.java:1195)
>      invoked at oracle.iam.ui.catalog.view.backing.CartReqBean.submitActionListener(CartReqBean.java:1097)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>      invoked at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>      invoked at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>      invoked at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:187)
>      invoked at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
>      invoked at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.util.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:53)
>      invoked at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.broadcastToMethodBinding(UIXComponentBase.java:1491)
>      invoked at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:183)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.broadcast(UIXRegion.java:184)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:111)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:395)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:115)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:102)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:111)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:395)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:115)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:96)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.broadcast(UIXRegion.java:184)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:102)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:111)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:395)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:115)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:96)
>      invoked at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.broadcastEvents(LifecycleImpl.java:1100)
>      invoked at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:446)
>      invoked at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>      invoked at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
>      invoked at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
>      invoked at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
>      invoked at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
>      invoked at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
>      invoked at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
>      invoked at oracle.help.web.rich.OHWFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
>      invoked at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:211)
>      invoked at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
>      invoked at oracle.adf.view.page.editor.webapp.WebCenterComposerFilter.doFilter(WebCenterComposerFilter.java:117)
>      invoked at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
>      invoked at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:133)
>      invoked at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:478)
>      invoked at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
>      invoked at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:478)
>
>
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' [14:11:54:382]: [JCoAPI] JCoClient before ping() on handle [1/84936186]
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' [14:11:54:382]: [JCoRFC] Executing function RFC_PING on handll [1/84936186]
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' [14:11:54:382]: [JCoRFC] getCodepage trying codepage 4103
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' [14:11:54:382]: [JCoRFC] getCodepage returns partner codepage 4103
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' [14:11:54:382]: [JCoRFC] Connection attributes:
>    DEST:                   SAP_SINERGIA
>    OWN_HOST:               **********
>    PARTNER_HOST:           ***********
>    SYSTNR:                 **
>    SYSID:                  ***
>    CLIENT:                 ***
>    USER:                   ******
>    LANGUAGE:               S
>    ISO_LANGUAGE:           ES
>    OWN_CODEPAGE:           4102
>    OWN_CHARSET:            UTF16
>    OWN_ENCODING:           utf-16
>    OWN_BYTES_PER_CHAR:     2
>    PARTNER_CODEPAGE:       4103
>    PARTNER_CHARSET:        UTF16
>    PARTNER_ENCODING:       utf-16
>    PARTNER_BYTES_PER_CHAR: 2
>    OWN_REL:                721
>    PARTNER_REL:            740
>    PARTNER_TYPE:           3
>    KERNEL_REL:             742
>    TRACE:
>    RFC_ROLE:               C
>    OWN_TYPE:               E
>    CPIC_CONVID:            00000000
>
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-
>    tuning)' [14:11:54:382]: [JCoRFC] Ping before RfcCall(1, RFC_PING, null, null, null)
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-
>    tuning)' [14:11:54:382]: [JCoRFC] Ping after RfcCall(1, RFC_PING, null, null, null)
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-
>    tuning)' [14:11:54:382]: [JCoRFC] Ping before RfcListen(1, 60000)
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-
>    tuning)' [14:11:54:431]: [JCoRFC] Ping after RfcListen(1, 60000)
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' [14:11:54:431]: [JCoRFC] Ping before RfcReceive(1, RFC_PING, null, null, null)
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' [14:11:54:431]: [JCoRFC] Ping after RfcReceive(1, RFC_PING, null, null, null)
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' [14:11:54:431]: [JCoAPI] JCoClient after ping() on handle [1/84936186] returns after 49 ms
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' [14:11:54:431]: [JCoAPI] Context.releaseConnection on destination SAP_SINERGIA [1/84936186]
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' [14:11:54:432]: [JCoAPI] PoolingFactory.releaseClient() handle 
>    [1/84936186] into pool SAP_SINERGIA|CONFIGURED_USER&100|OIMUSER|ES|2E545FD526DF90E53EA765E2FFDFAE37|CPIC0 [pool size: 1, peak limit: 2147483647, waiting threads: 0, currently used: 1]
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' [14:11:54:432]: [JCoRFC] Reset implicitely done by kernel of partner [1]
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' [14:11:54:437]: [JCoAPI] Context.getConnection on destination SAP_SINERGIA (state: destination = STATELESS, default = STATELESS)
>    [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' [14:11:54:437]: [JCoAPI] PoolingFactory.getClient() on pool SAP_SINERGIA|CONFIGURED_USER&100|OIMUSER|ES|2E545FD526DF90E53EA765E2FFDFAE37|CPIC0
>   [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' [14:11:54:438]: [JCoAPI] PoolingFactory.getClient() returns handle [1/84936186]
>      invoked at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.PoolingFactory.getClient(PoolingFactory.java:604)
>      invoked at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.ConnectionManager.getClient(ConnectionManager.java:115)
>      invoked at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.Context.getConnection(Context.java:194)
>      invoked at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.RfcDestination.ping(RfcDestination.java:1418)
>      invoked at org.identityconnectors.sap.SAPConnector.checkAlive(SAPConnector.java:193)
>      invoked at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.ConnectorPoolManager$ConnectorPoolHandler.testObject(ConnectorPoolManager.java:105)
>      invoked at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.ConnectorPoolManager$ConnectorPoolHandler.testObject(ConnectorPoolManager.java:74)
>      invoked at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.ObjectPool.borrowObject(ObjectPool.java:229)
>      invoked at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.ConnectorAPIOperationRunnerProxy.invoke(ConnectorAPIOperationRunnerProxy.java:83)
> ```

I don't know whether it is a connection error or another cause, I can see from Java, different data of SAP like users types, roles, profiles, etc. I've only been able to consult things, but I want to create a user, thing that I can't.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this exception but I can give a few guidelines regarding provisioning accounts in OIM for SAP target systems.
First verify that you are populating mandatory fields such as password and user ID. Make sure the initial password you set in the IT resource is compliant to the sap system. 
In addition some sap systems are configured to deny accounts created without a user group. 
My best guess on your exception is that you are possibly trying to provision an account with '.' character in it which is forbidden in sap. Second guess will be that the account is created in sap and a user object is returned to OIM with an attribute mapped to a field in your sap form which is set to a wrong data type (you have errors regarding writing data into OIM) . These are common issues, if you believe the issue is regarding connectivity - sometimes configuring new sap connections in OIM will require a restart of OIM. If you have any new info I would love to help. Good luck!